# Finding a file by extension

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to find files with .desktop extension in a specific directory in Python3. I tried the code snippet below but it didn't work as I wanted. I want it to be a single string value.

```py
import os, fnmatch
desktopfile = configparser.ConfigParser ()
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
script_tmp_dir = "/tmp/appiload/appinstall" # Geçici dizin (dosyalar burada ayıklanıyor)
desktopfilea=f"{script_tmp_dir}/squashfs-root/{str(find ('*.desktop', f'{script_tmp_dir}/squashfs-root/')}"
print(desktopfilea)
desktopfile.items()
```

Result:

```
/tmp/appiload/appinstall/squashfs-root/['/tmp/appiload/appinstall/squashfs-root/helloworld.desktop']
```

Comment: if you weant that first result, simply change `result.append(os.path.join(root, name))` to `return os.path.join(root, name)` - but you will miss out on others that also match.

Comment: alternatively:  `for i in find('*.desktop', f'{script_tmp_dir}/squashfs-root/'): desktopfilea=f"{script_tmp_dir}/squashfs-root/{i}";print(desktopfilea)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) instead of writing a function to do this job.

```py
import os, glob

desktopfile = configparser.ConfigParser ()

script_tmp_dir = "/tmp/appiload/appinstall" # Geçici dizin (dosyalar burada ayıklanıyor)
desktopfilea = glob.glob(f'{script_tmp_dir}/squashfs-root/*.desktop')
# desktopfilea = " ".join(desktopfilea) # Join them in one string, using space as seperator
print(str(desktopfilea))
desktopfile.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what do you mean but I made a simple program that will print all the files with the .desktop extension and save them to 2 files: applications.json in an array and applications.txt just written one after another.

I also have 2 versions of the program, one that will only print and save only the file names with extensions and other one that will print and save the whole path.

File names only:

```py
import os
import json

strApplications = ""
applications = []
for file in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))):
    if file.endswith(".desktop"):
        applications.append(file)

        with open("applications.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(applications, f)

        strApplications = strApplications + file + "\n"

        with open("applications.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(strApplications)

print(strApplications)
```

Full file path:

```py
import os
import json

cwd = os.getcwd()

files = [cwd + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(cwd) if f.endswith(".desktop")]

with open("applications.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(files, f)

with open("applications.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(files))

print("\n".join(files))
```